# Change listview contents depending on the item chosen in Combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, combobox

I have the following 3 items in a Combobox.

```
                    * All

                    * Item 1

                    * Item 2
```

Meanwhile, I have a listview like given below.

```
              * Item 1
                       - Sub - Item 1
                       - Sub - Item 2
                       - Sub - Item 3
              * Item 2
                       - Sub -Item 1
                       - Sub - Item 2
                       - Sub - Item 3
                       - Sub - Item 4
```

My requirement is like this. If the content chosen in the combobox is "Item 1", then what is displayed in the listview should be the following.

```
             * Item 1
                       - Sub - Item 1
                       - Sub - Item 2
                       - Sub - Item 3
```

Similarly, if the content chosen in the combobox is "Item 2", then what is displayed in the lisview should be the following.

```
            * Item 2
                       - Sub -Item 1
                       - Sub - Item 2
                       - Sub - Item 3
                       - Sub - Item 4
```

Finally, if "All" is chosen , then obviously it should display the following.

```
          * Item 1
                       - Sub - Item 1
                       - Sub - Item 2
                       - Sub - Item 3
          * Item 2
                       - Sub -Item 1
                       - Sub - Item 2
                       - Sub - Item 3
                       - Sub - Item 4
```

Can someone pls suggest a way to do this?

Comment: I have tried clearing the list view first in cmboBox_SelectionChanged event. And then tried binding a new item source to the list view. In the new item source, the chosen item has to be removed. struggling with that removal part too.

Comment: I think if your data structure is like this: A variable holding the group type (item 1, item 2), and a list of the subitems, than it's quite easy. You just say that if the group type not equals to the selected one, remove it. Maybe this is what you tried?

Comment: The confusing part is that this filtering should be done based on two combobox values. I have already done done because the object list that I am binding to the listview is contained in another object list which have binded to the other combobox. Therefore, filtering with that combobox was ok,. But keeping the values of the combobox ( the one I have posted above ) is not possible . I cleared the listview and checked whether "Item 1" exists in the itemsource of listview, If it is there, then I removed it and tried binding the new list of objects to the listview. But binding does not happen.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i wrote simple realization, hope this is what you need.
Put Xaml code into your Window:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ComboBox 
        x:Name="MyCombo" 
        DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
        SelectedValuePath="Name"
        SelectedIndex="0"
        />
    <ListView
        x:Name="MyList"
        Grid.Row="1"
        DisplayMemberPath="SubName"
        >
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="14" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

And some code-behind:

```
public class MyItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SubName { get; set; }
    public MyItem(string name, string subName)
    {
        Name = name;
        SubName = subName;
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var comboBoxItems = new List<MyItem>();
        comboBoxItems.Add(new MyItem("All", null));
        comboBoxItems.Add(new MyItem("Item 1", null));
        comboBoxItems.Add(new MyItem("Item 2", null));
        MyCombo.ItemsSource = comboBoxItems;

        var listViewItems = new List<MyItem>();
        listViewItems.Add(new MyItem("Item 1", "SubItem 1.1"));
        listViewItems.Add(new MyItem("Item 1", "SubItem 1.2"));
        listViewItems.Add(new MyItem("Item 1", "SubItem 1.3"));
        listViewItems.Add(new MyItem("Item 2", "SubItem 2.1"));
        listViewItems.Add(new MyItem("Item 2", "SubItem 2.2"));
        listViewItems.Add(new MyItem("Item 2", "SubItem 2.3"));
        listViewItems.Add(new MyItem("Item 2", "SubItem 2.4"));

        CollectionView view = (CollectionView) CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(listViewItems);
        PropertyGroupDescription groupDescription = new PropertyGroupDescription("Name");
        view.GroupDescriptions.Add(groupDescription);
        view.Filter = itemObject =>
            {
                MyItem item = (MyItem) itemObject;
                string comboName = (string) MyCombo.SelectedValue;
                return item.Name == comboName || comboName == "All";
            };
        MyCombo.SelectionChanged += (s, e) => view.Refresh();
        MyList.ItemsSource = view;
    }
}
```

Main moment here is CollectionView class and other related classes. It is right way to work with ListView grouping (as far as i know).

Comment: I used your code in my project. It generates a statckoverflow exception. I found the line where it is happening. That is the last line.                        MyList.ItemsSource = view;              I have already set the item source of my listview in .xaml code. Itemsource is an object list contained in the selected object of the other combobox I was talikng about. Do you know why this is happening ?

Comment: This is happening becase i wrote my code without your part of code with "I have already set the item source...". To see fullworking project - create empty WPF project in VS, then paste XAML code into <Window> tag's content. Then copy-paste c# code into windows code-behind. This will work (if need - i can send you my project files).

I don't know - why my and your merged code not working. Need to see this merged code, especially, if you say that "Itemsource is an object list contained in the selected object of the other combobox"-this is additional conditions, and appropriating code is welcome

Answer (score 0):

Hope you have declared classes for your **Items** and **SubItems**. Then you need to bind collection of your Items to the Combobox and SubItems to the ListView in the MainWindow. What you need to do is Write your code in **ComboBox_SelectionChanged** method to reset the current ItemSource of the ListView and Bind new item source which is based on the selected combobox Item.

I have tried something like this, [**Check here**](http://the--semicolon.blogspot.com/p/change-listview.html).